# How to copy whole directory to perticular folder in perl script

Tags: perl, ubuntu, command

I am trying to copy zipped files which are stored in one directory to another folder by matching there names.
Below image are the folder names which is the input for my program.
[image]

From this list i am taking only "Sample_51" folder , inside this folder i have Zipped files like below,
[image]
Now i need to copy all "R1" name files to R1 folder and all "R2" named files to R2 folder.

Below i have tried to do so , help me out to do as explained above,

```
#! use/bin/perl

print "Enter Folder name \n";
print "File name: ";
chomp( my $Filename = <> );

system("mkdir R1");
system("mkdir R2");

opendir( DIR, "$Filename" ) or die "cannot open directory";
foreach my $name ( readdir(DIR) ) {
    next if ( $name =~ /^\./ );
    next if ( $name =~ /^\.\./ );

    if ( $Filename =~ /\S+(R\d)/ ) {

        system("cp -r $Filename R1");
    }
    else {
        system("cp -r $Filename R2");
    }
}
```

After copying this one more step is there, than i will update after fixing this issue,
thanks in advance

Comment: File::Copy and perdoc -f mkdir

Comment: Also - what problem are you having?

Comment: its not copying to particular directory

Comment: Hi @aditya please don't remove the question here. If you wish you can add to previous question or ask a new question.

Comment: how to retrive the question again, because i have updated by deleting that. now how can i retrive that?

Comment: make it this question again http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31535859/edit/4bcc4f8d-edee-42f4-87a2-145d01c15923 .Use edit option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `File::Copy` to copy the files. As @sobrique said `$Filename =~ /\S+(R\d)` it matches any digit followed by R.But I guess you are intersted in `R1` and `R2` only. Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Copy;
use strict;
use warnings;

print"Enter Folder name \n";
print"File name: ";
chomp(my $Filename=<>);

mkdir "R1";
mkdir "R2";


opendir(DIR,"$Filename") or die "cannot open directory";
foreach my $name (readdir(DIR))
{
next if ($name =~ /^\./);
if($name =~ /R1/) { #compare $name not $Filename
   copy("$Filename/$name", "R1"); # copy the file from folder to R1 directory
   }
elsif($name =~ /R2/){
   copy("$Filename/$name","R2"); ## copy the file from folder to R2 directory
    }
  }
```

Comment: Its working sir, my next step is pooling the data, consider updated question . thanks for ur answer !!!!

Comment: did u got my new question? kindly work on that its very urgent

Comment: Don't remove the previous question. When you edited you removed the question . Please rollback the edit and ask a new question regarding the text copy part.

Comment: how to retrive the question again, because i have updated by deleting that. now how can i retrive that?

Comment: i have asked new question which is contineation of this question, kindly help me out

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this line:

```
if ( $Filename =~ /\S+(R\d)/ ) {
```

Because what it's matching is `R` followed by any digit. So will be true for files called `R1`, `R2`, `R9` or indeed `R99999`

You need to capture the result of that regular expression match. (By the way - an unanchored `\S+` isn't going to do much in this example either. That just means 'one or more non spaces' before the R.

How about:

```
 if ( my ( $R_Num ) = ( $Filename =~ /_(R\d+)_/ ) {
     print "R number is $R_Num\n"; 
 }
```

Because then you can work based on what that's set to (and if the match fails, the `if` will test false).

Comment: its just creating folders but not copying anything